# pl sql dbms_lob.substr or regex_substr get text between new lines

Tags: oracle, plsql

I got a table with a clob field that contains the next string:

```
"hello world Chr(13)
hello world 2 chr(13)
hello world 3"
```

I m trying to get the text "`hello world 2`" between the first and the last break line but I still cannot.

I try it with `DBMS_LOB.INSTR` and `regexp_substr` without success... anybody can help me here?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure that is your input string, and not 'hello world' || chr(13) || ...? Two differences: strings are enclosed in single quotes, not double; and chr(13) is a function that returns a single character (caret return) - the way you wrote it, the letters chr.... have no special meaning, there is no "line break" in the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your string is in fact as I suggested in my comment (and reflected in the test string below):

```
with inputs ( str ) as (
       select to_clob('hello world' || chr(13) || 'hello world 2' || chr(13) ||
                                                           'hello world 3') from dual
     )
select dbms_lob.substr(str, 
                dbms_lob.instr(str, chr(13), 1, 2) - dbms_lob.instr(str, chr(13), 1, 1), 
                dbms_lob.instr(str, chr(13), 1, 1))           as second_line
from   inputs;



SECOND_LINE                                                                     
----------------
hello world 2
```

Whenever you must deal with CLOBs, use the dbms_lob functions; they are much faster than regular expression solutions.